# 404 when deleting a mongo document via express, mongoose, and angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose, angular-ui-router

I'm new to using the MEAN stack, have learned some of the basics to add data to mongodb using mongoose, express, and ui-router. However, I can't figure out how to delete a document. Whenever I try, I get 404 errors, even though it looks like the link should be correct. Would someone please help? Be kind, my code might be way off...

Here is my angular file:

```
var app = angular.module('updateTracker', ['ui.router']);

app.factory('courses', ['$http', function($http){
  var o = {
    courses: []
  };

  o.getAll = function() {
    return $http.get('/courses').success(function(data){
      angular.copy(data, o.courses);
    });
  };

  o.create = function(course) {
    return $http.post('/courses', course).success(function(data){
        o.courses.push(data);
    });
  };

  o.get = function(id) {
      return $http.get('/courses/' + id).then(function(res){
        return res.data;
      });
    };

  o.addEntry = function(id, entry) {
      return $http.post('/courses/' + id + '/entries', entry);
    };

  o.changeLesson = function(course) {
    return $http.put('/courses/' + course._id + '/changeLesson')
    .success(function(data){
        course.lesson = "New Lesson";
    });
  };

  o.removeCourse = function(course) {
    return $http.delete('/courses/' + course._id + '/removeCourse')
    .success(function (data, status) {
       console.log(data);
      });
  };

  return o;
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope',
'courses',
function($scope, courses){
  $scope.courses = courses.courses;

    $scope.addCourse = function(){
      if(!$scope.lesson || $scope.lesson === '') { return; }
      courses.create({
        lesson: $scope.lesson,
        course: $scope.course,
        curriculum: $scope.curriculum
      });
      $scope.lesson = '';
      $scope.course = '';
      $scope.curriculum = '';
    };

    $scope.changeLesson = function(course){
      courses.changeLesson(course);
    };

    $scope.removeCourse = function(course) {
        courses.removeCourse(course);
    };
}]);

app.controller('CoursesCtrl', [
'$scope',
'courses',
'course',
function($scope, courses, course){
    $scope.course = course;

    $scope.addEntry = function(){
      // if($scope.version === '') { return; }
      courses.addEntry(course._id, {
        version: $scope.version,
        notes: $scope.notes,
        statusCode: $scope.statusCode, 
        statusMessage: $scope.statusMessage,
        author: 'user'
      }).success(function(entry) {
        $scope.course.entries.push(entry);
      });
      $scope.version = '';
      $scope.notes = '';
      $scope.statusCode = '';
      $scope.statusMessage = '';
    };
}]);

app.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            resolve: {
                postPromise: ['courses', function(courses){
                    return courses.getAll();
                }]
            }
        })
        .state('courses', {
          url: '/courses/{id}',
          templateUrl: '/courses.html',
          controller: 'CoursesCtrl',
          resolve: {
            course: ['$stateParams', 'courses', function($stateParams, courses) {
              return courses.get($stateParams.id);
            }]
          }
        });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home')
}]);
```

My routes:

```
    var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Course = mongoose.model('Course');
var Entry = mongoose.model('Entry');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;

router.get('/courses', function(req, res, next) {
    Course.find(function(err, courses) {
        if(err){ return next(err); }

        res.json(courses);
    });
});

router.post('/courses', function(req, res, next) {
    var course = new Course(req.body);

    course.save(function(err, course) {
        if(err){return next(err); }

        res.json(course);
    });
});

router.param('course', function(req, res, next, id) {
  var query = Course.findById(id);

  query.exec(function (err, course){
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!course) { return next(new Error('can\'t find course')); }

    req.course = course;
    return next();
  });
});

router.get('/courses/:course', function(req, res, next) {
  req.course.populate('entries', function(err, course) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    res.json(course);
  });
});

router.post('/courses/:course/entries', function(req, res, next) {
  var entry = new Entry(req.body);
  entry.course = req.course;

  entry.save(function(err, entry){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    req.course.entries.push(entry);
    req.course.save(function(err, course) {
      if(err){ return next(err); }

      res.json(entry);
    });
  });
});

router.put('/courses/:course/changeLesson', function(req, res, next) {
  req.course.changeLesson(function(err, course){
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    res.json(course);
  });
});

router.delete('courses/:course', function(req, res) {
  Course.remove({
    _id : mongodb.ObjectID(req.params.course)
  }, function(err) {
    if(err) { res.send(err);}
    console.log("remove id");
  })
});

router.param('entry', function(req, res, next, id) {
  var query = Entry.findById(id);

  query.exec(function (err, entry){
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!entry) { return next(new Error('can\'t find entry')); }

    req.entry = entry;
    return next();
  });
});
```

and my course Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    lesson: String,
    course: String,
    curriculum: String,
    entries: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Entry'}]
});

CourseSchema.methods.changeLesson = function(cb) {
  this.lesson = "Update Lesson";
  this.save(cb);
};

mongoose.model('Course', CourseSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `/` in the begining of `router.delete` and `/removeCourse` at end as well as did not return value using either res.send or res.json or res.end, etc. This should be like bellow

```
router.delete('/courses/:course/removeCourse', function(req, res) {
  Course.remove({
    _id : req.params.course
  }, function(err) {
    if(err) { 
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      res.json({});
      console.log("remove id");
   }
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help- it seemed to fix the 404 error, but not I'm receiving a 500 error. I feel helpless, but I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are getting error while deleting course. You need to debug and fix. I have updated code and `if(err) { console.log(err);`. You may check error or let me what error throwing

Comment: Hmm- that's the part I'm having trouble with- it's not logging the error- ie: I don't think it's getting to the router.delete function, or I'd be seeing the console.log(err). I'm not even getting my log in my angular file- when I run o.delete (see above) I see a log that it runs the function, but it doesn't print a log after .success.

Comment: I added an error handler in my angular factory, and the error says 'mongo is not defined'- why would that be the case if my other functions are working?

Comment: You need to remove `mongodb.ObjectID(req.params.course)` and use `req.params.course` because you did not define `mongodb`. I have updated code, pleas have a look

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked to remove it from the database- the only issue I'm having now is that it doesn't show as removed until I refresh the page.

Comment: I think I got it- i added the splice method in the success portion of my removeCourse function. Thanks again!